# Apache proxy https to https with different CA

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to set Apache proxy to terminate https connection with a certificate signed by CA01 and to proxy it to another https with another certificate signed by CA02. Is it possible to do?

[proxy scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOaf5.png)